# "I appointed Mary as founding President, XYZ" "I recruited Mary to become founding President, XYZ"

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure, usage

> I appointed Mary **as** founding President, XYZ.

> I recruited Mary **to become** founding President, XYZ.

None of these sentences really sound right. What would be the correct way to write them?

Comment: It depends entirely on who the speaker is and what relationship they have to Mary and to XYZ. Also, if she is 'founding president' she must have played an important role in setting up XYZ, so she is unlikely to have been recruited by another person.

Comment: I have to agree with Kate on this one - the premise of the question is nonsensical, which makes it hard to provide sensible suggestions.

Comment: The first Cambridge definition for [**recruit**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/recruit) is *to **persuade** someone to work for a company or become a new member of an organization*. Another common implication is that the person doing the hiring often has to ***look for, seek out*** the person who will be recruited. You might (nepotistically) ***appoint your wife*** to the board, but we wouldn't normally say you ***recruited*** her (except "semi-facetiously").

Comment: One would not appoint or recruit a *founder*.  A founder is a founder based on what they have done, not what has been ascribed to them.  Saying that you will appoint someone as a founder is like saying you will appoint someone to be the tallest person in the room.  The tallest person in the room is the tallest person in the room.  A founder is a founder.

Comment: Perhaps you had a ceremony to make the title official.  In that case you would say,  We *recognized* Mary as a founder [at a luncheon today].

Comment: "recruited her to become X" also just sounds weird to this US English speaker.  You recruited her for the position of X, and she became X, but you didn't "recruit her to become X".

Answer (score 1):

As Ms. Bunting said, the premise of the question is weird, but I shall try to deal with the linguistic issues.

The word “president” is both a title and an office. In lists, it is common to see the form

> President, XYZ

as an abbreviation of

> the president of XYZ

But outside the context of lists or the address block of a letter, the usual written usage is

> the president of XYZ

That usage focuses on the office rather than title.

Capitalizing focuses on title.

There is no such title and no such office as Founding President. In the context of your sentences, “founding” is not idiomatic.

So you are correct that

founding President, XYZ

sounds weird, not just as a matter of English usage but also as a matter of normal practice in governance of organizations.

> The board appointed Mary N. Jones as the initial president of XYZ.

Comment: _Founding President_ implies to me that she had been offered the position by the board/committee in recognition of her leading role in starting whatever organisation XYZ is.

Comment: Ms. Bunting This may be one of those differences between American and British usages. There is no office entitled “Founding President” in the U.S. Moreover, the appellation “founding president” would normally be used **retrospectively** if the person initially in authority after an organization was created put it on sound footing. People who were instrumental in creating an organization before it existed legally might well be “founders,” but founders do not hold an office; it reflects historical fact rather than legally recognized office.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that it was an official title that we use, just that that was my understanding of the meaning of the phrase.